# NetBeans program linking

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

1 main program 2 JFrame programs.

How do I use the main program to call the JFrames to run during the main programs execution chromatically? (One at a time, one pops up user interacts and hits ok, the next frame pops up)

I've tried using this, but it executes both of the frames at the same time.

```
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new chooseGender().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either hide or dispose of the current JFrame.

To hide, you can call the `.setVisible(false)` method, or if you no longer need the JFrame, simply call the `.dispose()` method.

Note, you should create the new JFrame and hide/remove the current one, ideally in the event handler of the button which the user presses to go to the next screen.

Comment: No problem. Maybe you should take a look at some tutorials or Sun's API. Usually these save you time and let you make correct code, not to mention that you can learn more :)